# result of mongoose query from a loop won't updating the result array in node.js

Tags: node.js, function, mongoose, callback

```
var row = ['570eb3c03a118b071fa6e487','570eb3c03a118b071fa6e488','570eb3c03a118b071fa6e489'];
var gridItemsFound=[]
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length && numOfGrids != noOfgridFound; i++) {
   var row_id = rows[i];
   (function (row_id) {
     grids.findOne({'_id': row_id}, function (err, result) { 
       for (var j = 0; j < result.cols.length && numOfGrids!=noOfgridFound; j++) {

         if (result.cols[j].purchased == false){
           noOfgridFound++;
           gridItemsFound.push({row: row_id, col: result.cols[j].id});
         }
       };
     });
   })(row_id);
 };
 console.log(gridItemsFound);
```

> after pushing all the result to the array, its not alter when i console it after the loop.

Comment: There are so many things that could be happening here - does the callback actually fire? Is there an error in the callback? Does `result` actually contain anything? Is `result.cols[j].purchased` actually `false`? (FYI `!result.cols[j].purchased` would yield the same result)

Comment: everything happening fine except updations i am doind on array gridItemsFound wont seen when i console the array outside. result variable contaning values, using those values i can loop through and  some result.cols[j].purchased will be false, in that case it will update the array successfully, all those things are tested myself. my only issue is i am updating the array but not visible those changes when i console outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findOne` operation is I/O bound which means updates to your array will happen *asynchronously*, in a nut shell what this means is your loop will finish before your callbacks would have run meaning no updates to the array would have occurred at that point.

To summarise, you effectively need to wait for all your callbacks to run before you continue, I'd recommend using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) lib as it helps get rid of a lot of boiler plate code

```
var rows = [...]
async.map(rows, function(rowId, callback) {
    grids.findOne({'_id': rowId}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            var notPurchased = result.cols.filter(function(col) {
                return !col.purchase;
            }).map(function(col) {
                return { row: rowId, col: col.id };
            });
            noOfGridFound += notPurchased.length;
            callback(null, notPurchased);   
        }
    });
}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: @user3045354 your welcome, if this solution solved your problem then please upvote & accept the answer (that's basically the jist of how the site works).

Comment: sorry James, inn-order to up-vote you i need at-least 15 points in the site. but  i don,t have that much. i am a beginner in this.